# Plot only some columns with seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am working on this diabetes [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database) which contains many columns.

Normally, I can choose some specific columns that I need with this code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy, vars=['Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness'], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()
```

How can I use the slide index to choose the columns? Because I want to plot all the columns but it will return a lot of plots that hard to see.

I just want to plot the first 3 columns then the remaining.

```
# Plot the first 3 columns
plt.figure()
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy[:, 1:3], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()

# Plot the remain columns
plt.figure()
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy[, 3:], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()
```

With this code, I will get this error:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid key
```

**Update:**
Using `iloc` method get this error:

```
plt.figure()
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy.iloc[:, 1:3], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: After inspecting the data more thoroughly, I understand that the issue is a bit more subtle, especially when it comes to the visualization: Although you want to subset the columns you select, since you are passing the into the `data` argument of `sns.pairplot`, those columns *must* also include "Outcome", so you can vary the hue/color of the pairplot based on this column. One possible way to solve this is the following:

```py
# Plot the first 3 columns
plt.figure()
cols_to_plot = dataset_copy.columns[1:3].tolist() + ['Outcome'] # explicitly add the column "Outcome" to your list of columns to plot
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy[cols_to_plot], hue ="Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()

# Plot the remain columns
plt.figure()
cols_to_plot = dataset_copy.columns[3:].tolist() # Take the remaining columns for the second plot; those already include "Outcome"
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy[cols_to_plot], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
plt.show()
```

This returns

[image: first_3_cols]

for the first chart.

If you don't like creating a `cols_to_plot` variable separately, you can also do the following:

```
sns.pairplot(dataset_copy, vars = dataset_copy.columns[1:3], hue ="Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])
```

effectively passing the whole dataframe into the `pairplot`, but only choosing to plot a specific subset of columns, passed as a list into the `vars` argument.

---

Original:

What you have above seems correct. Instead of

```
dataset_copy[:, 1:3]
```

use

```
dataset_copy.iloc[:, 1:3]
```

The error occurs because when using square bracket slicing, you can *either* ask to get the rows (e.g. `df[0:5]`) *or* to get some specific columns (e.g. `df['Alpha']`). To slice by both index and columns, you need to use `iloc` (for location-based indexing) or `loc` (for label-based indexing). See the more detailed explanation in the Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics)

Comment: Using `iloc` will make the last column which is `Outcome` got `KeyError`.

Comment: @huy you are completely right! I edited the answer to reflect the full problem

Comment: really silly question: cant you just drop the variables (columnd ) you dont need, at least in a temporary df? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can use following way

`import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

sns.pairplot(dataset_copy[['Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness','Outcome']], hue = "Outcome", markers=["o", "s"])

plt.show()`