# Key Error with sns.pairplot when using hue

Tags: python, seaborn, pairplot

I am working on a machine learning project, specifically wine quality classification and I am having problem with sns.pairplot. I have run the following

```
df = pd.read_csv("winequality-red.csv", sep=';')
df.head()
column_labels = data.columns
print(column_labels)
```

and I get this which is perfect.
[image]

But when running the code I get this error below:
[image]

This is what I am trying :

```
sns.pairplot(df.iloc[:, :7], hue='pH')
plt.show()
```

If I change the ":7" to include the column "pH" then I get the plots, but should it not work without including?

Comment: visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556501/plot-only-some-columns-with-seaborn-pairplot>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are specifying a hue, that column must be included in the chart. If you remove the `hue='pH'` specification, then the plot would work without the pH column; similarly, if you set hue to a column that is included, you would have no issues.

The issue is that you are telling sns to place a hue on a column that is not included in the chart.

Comment: Oh so I definitely need to include that column? Because I believe that I did not find anything in the sns.pairplot documentation that specifies that.

Comment: If you are setting "hue" to be used in the chart, but then "hue" is looking for a column that is not present, you will encounter an error. Hue must be set to a column that is present in the chart.

Comment: Note that depending on the number of values in `pH`, using a hue might not give a legible graph (and could take a lot of time to compute). Consider using `cut` on this column.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

sns.pairplot(df, vars = df.columns[0:5], hue ="pH")
plt.show()

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: taken from <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556501/plot-only-some-columns-with-seaborn-pairplot>